# run Kibana from Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

when I run the Kibana locally, I just use bin/elasticsearch and bin/kibana. But now I have to deploy it into docker. Because I have a kibana plugin and I also have some changes for the JS files(those files will be rewritten if a new plugin is installed). May I use the way like copy my local directory and files into a docker container and use something like bin/elasticsearch, bin/kibana to run kibnan to keep all my changes?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create another `Dockerfile` referencing the `kibana` build and use [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) into that container.

Something like:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.0.0
COPY random.js <where the file needs to be copied>
```

Then you build the container with `docker build` and run that container instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So this kibana docker image has the same files as the one (no docker image) that I download from the website? And with elasticsearch, do I need one docker container for elasticsearch? Or elastic and kibana can be put into the same container. I also have a shell need to run based on kibana

Comment: Yep, taking the upstream docker container, you "layer" your changes on top of it, by the `COPY` command. Take a look [here](https://vsupalov.com/docker-image-layers/) for how layers work with containers.

Comment: I got an error there is no kibana/bin/kibana

Comment: I strongly suggest you take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3c-iBn73dDE) and learn the basics of `docker` from there you should be able to figure out your issues.